# Displaying Numbers in Certain Shapes

Tags: java

I just thought of this problem 15 minutes ago and even though it appears insanely easy I'm having a serious problem coming up with an answer.

Basically what I would like to do is based on a number (n) given by the user, I would like to draw a square shape.

Example: let's say the user gives the number 2, the result should be:

```
12
43
```

Now, suppose the user gives the number 3, the result should be:

```
123
894
765
```

etc..

Please don't give me the solution to this problem, I just want a clue or two to get me going.

I thought about doing it with a simple java class but I'm still struggling to get past the first condition:

```
public class DrawSquareWithNumbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your number: ");
        int number = scanner.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i <= number; i++) {
            if (i<number)
             System.out.print(i); 
             if (i>=number) {
                 System.out.println("\n"+i);
             }
        }

    }
}
```

Any tip? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just thinking a loop from 1 to number *number is required

Comment: It'd be very cool to calculate what you've to print with a formula or something, but I think you need to store your square matrix before printing it. Doing so would make it easy, just iterate through the positions in spiraling order.

Comment: That's a great tip, Jorge. I'll do that and get back to you.

Comment: See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-a-given-matrix-in-spiral-form/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think I just put way too much time in this but it's a fun challenge so I thought let's give it a go.

I implented a code version for this solution and it works quite well although it's probably not the cleanest as I approached the whole problem backwards.

Here is my solution to try out online (note it's severely unoptimized and by no ways good Java code. It's a quick and dirty implementation to be honest):

> https://ideone.com/97JB7Y

So the idea is quite simple: We first calculate the correct value for each position in a matrix and then we print that matrix out.

Let's go over it in a bit more detail:

We start of by creating the Matrix for our values to print:

With a given size `n` this is

```
int[][] values = new int[n][n];
```

Now we want to calculate the correct value at each point. I chose to tackle it the "wrong way" around by not starting at the first point but at the center of the spiral.

Basically imagine this matrix with `n = 3`:

```
[1][2][3]
[8][9][4]
[7][6][5]
```

Instead of at `1` I just start at `9`. Reasoning for this is that it's actually easier to calculate the position spiraling out from a point over spiraling in to a point.

So starting at this center point we spiral out from there in a circular fashion. For the matrix

```
[1][2]
[4][3]
```

this means we visit 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1. And then just save the correct value in the matrix.

Only problem with my approach is that for a matrix with uneven size (3, 5, 7, etc.) I still visit the points in spiraling order, for 3x3 the order of visiting is e.g. 9 -> 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1 -> 8 -> 7 -> 6 -> 5, as visualized in this perfect picture I totally drew in Paint:

[image: Order of Evaluation]

This leads to the result matrix being inversed as such:

```
[5][6][7]
[4][9][8]
[3][2][1]
```

This small problem is easily fixed though by simply printing the matrix out inversed once more should `n%2 != 0`.

Hope I could help with maybe a different approach to the problem.

Comment: I like your answer a lot. But would you be so kind as to explain to me some of the lines which I didn't understand? Like:

1. `double r = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(i));` /* What's the r and why did you calculate it like that?. */
2. The formula to calculate the row and col variables seems quite complex to me. Could you explain those two lines a little bit? 
3. Could you please also explain the following line `values[row + (n / 2)][col + ((n - 1) / 2)] = (n * n) - i;` ?
4. What's the use of this condition `if (n % 2 == 0)`?
5. And finally, how did you "think" to come up with the answer?

Comment: "in this perfect picture I totally drew in Paint" :D cheers, original approach starting from the middle

Comment: @JesseJames the basic idea is to have 2 functions that always swing between 0 -> 1 -> 0 -> -1 -> 0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 1 -> 0 -> -1 -> -2 -> -1 -> 0 and so on and so on. It basically just calculates with some adapted vector math a point that rotates outwards from (0,0) and maps it to integer values. For your third point: The result starts at (0/0) in order to map this to our matrix we need to shift the index a bit. The row is always shifted by `n/2` and  the column is always shifted by `(n-1)/2`. You can verify that with mathematical induction if you want to ;)

Comment: 4. The condition is to simply check if we have a matrix with an odd width/height as those matrixes are constructed inversed. That's what I tried to visualize with my Paint image. And 5. Had a project back when VR was getting big to visualize a solar system. Objects spiraling out from somewhere were one of the things we did back there. Basically could take the formulas from there so I figured why not ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to make nxn matrix with user entered number. So you can check the input and then you can use loop as for(i=1; i<=n; i++) for rows and similarly for  column(for j=0;j<=n;j++) and then you can print your desired shape. Since you have asked to give you idea only so I am not posting any code here. If in case you get stuck somewhere you can refer : https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-a-given-matrix-in-spiral-form/amp/

Comment: I think he wants the numbers in a spiral shape, so starting from i = 0 j = 0 wouldnt work.

Comment: Thats just an idea

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let's give this a try. First let's assume you'll have to store the matrix before printing it and that there's no magic formula that allows you to print what you need in a single iteration.

Now, you've the NxN matrix, for example for 3 it'd be 3x3, 9 positions. Instead of solving it with a series of ifs in an ugly way, you could use direction vectors for a cleaner solution. Also assume for now that you've another NxN matrix filled with booleans, all set to false, that will represent the already printed positions in the NxN matrix that you will print in the end. When you write a number in the final NxN matrix, you put the same position's boolean to true in the boolean matrix.

So for example, you want to print the positions of the first row, 1 2 3. You are displacing to the right to print. This'd be the direction (1,0), aka the starting direction vector. You advance through the NxN matrix using this coordinates. When you go outside the matrix (in the example, your x position is 3) you decrease your x position by one and you "spin" your direction vector (this should be done in a separate function). (1,0) would spin to (0,-1). You keep using this vector to iterate your matrix, spinning as necesary. After the first whole circle, you will get to an already printed position before going outside the matrix. So after every print you've to check not only if you go outside the matrix, but also if that position has already a number on it. For this, you use the boolean matrix.

This is how I'd solve it, there are probably many other ways (and better ones). For starters you could use null, or a mark, in the final matrix and save yourself the booleans one.

Answer (score 0):

- Create the result matrix beforehand, and declare a variable for the current number, starting value = 1, the current co-ordinates, starting with (0,0), the stepping direction starting with "to the right"
- Start loop
- Calculate the co-ordinates of next step, and check it
- If it is off the matrix, then change direction, and re calculate, re-check
- If free, then put the number in the matrix, increment it, and loop
- If it is not free, then end loop, print out result matrix